# How do I exec more than one command?

Tags: bash

My login script `~/.profile` ends with the command

```
exec startx > ~/.xsession-errors 2>&1
```

I would like to run a second command `foo` when `startx` is done so I tried

```
exec { startx > ~/.xsession-errors 2>&1; foo; }
```

but that results in a syntax error. Any clues?

Comment: How about `exec sh -c 'startx > ~/.xsession-errors 2>&1; foo'`

Comment: What about putting it in your shell's .logout file? Or in your ~/.xsession file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller As far as I understand, `~/.bash_logout` is only run when `exit` or Ctrl-D is invoked.

Comment: @glennjackman That will indeed work, thanks! However, I think yaegashi's solution is bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't return to the script when `exec`'ed command terminates.  Therefore you can use `exec` only for the last command run in the script.

```
startx > ~/.xsession-errors 2>&1
exec foo
# You get here if exec foo failed
echo "Unable to exec foo" >&2
```